# Passing data between different views failure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I get the `userID` on Router and pass to View.

Router data transfer code:

```
AdminPanelView.usr = m_login.toJSON().userID;
console.log(AdminPanelView.usr); //print user id
```

AdminPanelView.js

```
var usr = new UserModel();
var addAdminPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    save: function(usr) {
        console.log({ usr: usr.toJSON() }); // print the screenshot's value on line 52
    }
});

return {
    addAdminPanelView: addAdminPanelView,
    usr: usr
}
```

How do I fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for edited@EmileBergeron